# Javascript function accepts string and adds it to array, simple web shop

Tags: javascript, html

New to javascript, need help adding name of item to array. It throws error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at addToCart (navbar.js:32). Just this is my code it works when concatenating a string

```
<div class="productprice"><div class="pull-right"><a href="#" onclick ="addToCart('Cabernet Sauvignon, Year 2016');" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm my-1" role="button">BUY</a></div>

var finalOrder = new Array();

function addToCart(name){  
    this.finalOrder.push(name);
    alert(finalOrder.toString());
}
```

EDIT:
Changed to this, random goes through but same error goes again
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at addToCart

```
var finalOrder = [];

function addToCart(name){  
    alert("random");
    finalOrder.push(name);
    alert(finalOrder.toString());    
}
```

Comment: `this` is going to be undefined.

Comment: just remove `this.`

Comment: `this` is a component of JavaScript's object-oriented API. It's a major pain point for beginners. I advise you avoid using it until you have a firm understanding of where it's needed and how it's meant to be used properly.

Comment: @DanielA.White Still getting the same error

Comment: also: Learn to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.orgdocs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)  (or a framework) instead of inline event handlers like `onclick="function"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` only refers to the scope of the function where you are calling it and not to the global scope where your `finalOrder` array is defined. By removing the `this.` then you will be referencing the variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
finalOrder= []

function addToCart(name){  
     finalOrder.push(name);
     alert(finalOrder.toString());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can just specify an array using `var finalOrder = [];`.

But the error right here is the current scope. When you use `this` reserved keyword in the function, it will refer to the function scope, that in that case is `window` object.

To get it running, just change

```
...
function addToCart(name){
  finalOrder.push(name);
  alert(finalOrder.toString());
}
```

In the newest version of javascript (You probably heard about ecmascript before), you can do:

```
...
const addToCart = name => ([ ...finalOrder, name ]);
```

If you're coming from C#, it'll probably make sense!

Comment: @thismarcoantinio i am still getting the same error after changing it

Comment: @CautionPackage did you removed the this? I've tested it here and worked!

Comment: @thismarcoantinio yes, i posted edited code.. can array printed like that in alert?

Comment: @CautionPackage you can view how i made it here: https://codepen.io/thismarcoantonio/pen/wjBRjx.

Also, don't forget to load your .js file before the body closing tag